# GF-SG Error in calculating area: User memory limit exceeded

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat

I am a newcomer to GEE.
When I finally calculated the area of NDSI, I encountered the issue of 'user memory limit exceeded'. Shrinking the research area to a small size does not work. How can I solve this problem?

Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e8b0743af3b86200b68a11a28f30c1e0

This code was originally designed to calculate NDVI, but I have modified them to calculate NDSI without modifying the variable name. Therefore, please ignore its naming and go directly to the final calculation area issue.

```
//export area
var areaImage = finalImageAbove.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6));
var stats_area = areaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: Subarea,
  scale: 500,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  tileScale :16,
  bestEffort: true
  }).get('constant');
print('area km²',stats_area);
```

Comment: It's a 500+ LOC script and require external libraries, so it's not really probable that someone will help you analyze this in detail. After glancing, an immediate tip would be to try to avoid converting collections to list. You might be forced to export intermediary results as assets before being able to calculate the area.